# How to set default style for widgets in pyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to set default style for all widgets in my application. I found [this page](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtktutorial/ch-settingwidgetattributes.html) and read that there is `set_default_style()` function. The problem is I cannot find it anywhere.

In witch package / module / class i can find this function?
Is there any other way to avoid setting styles for every widget with `gtk.Widget.set_style()` method?

Answer (score 6):

Widget.set_default_style() is deprecated since 3.0. You don't mention what version you are running but I'll go ahead and assume it's 3.x.

What you want is a [Gtk.CSSProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) (which you can build either from a string or from a css file), and attach this custom style provider to the style context. Something like this:

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider ()

css = """
GtkWindow {
    background-color: #F00;
}
"""

style_provider.load_from_data (css);

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen (Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
                                          style_provider,
                                          Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Take a look at the CSSProvider documentation for more details on the exact css format.

EDIT: actually you mention pygtk in the title -- I guess that means GTK+ 2.x? In that case the answer is *not* what I posted, and I really don't remember ye olden ways anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I just stumbled into this, and by brute-force experimenting, I ended up using:

```
widget2.set_style(widget.rc_get_style())
```

for an example, see:

[Templating overflowing content with glade and pygtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460848/templating-overflowing-content-with-glade-and-pygtk/20463925#20463925)

Not sure if it'd help in this case, though...